# Divide one CSS column in 2 rows

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/9877/6E2pQ/2/
What I want do is have columncontent1 on the left and columncontent2 and columncontent3 stacked on the right side.  see the jsfiddle.  How do I fix the css? I am running out of ideas. Is the error in the css or the way the div placed in the body:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
.columncontainer1{
width:1001px;
position:relative;
border:0px;
background-color:#fffffa;
overflow:hidden;
 }
.columncontainer2{
float:left;
position:relative;
right:300px;
border-right:1px solid #0a0a0a;
background-color:#f5f5f5;
 }
 .columncontainer3{
float:left;
position:relative;
bottom: 10px
border-right:1px solid #0a0a0a;
background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
.columncontent1{
float:left;
width:680px;
position:relative;
background-color:#933;
border: 1px;
left:300px;
padding:10px;
overflow:hidden;
 }
.columncontent2{
float:left;
width:280px;
position:relative;
background-color:#FFF;
border: 2px;
left:301px;
padding:10px;
overflow:hidden;
 }
 .columncontent3{
float:left;
width:280px;
position:relative;
left:301px;
border: 4px;
background-color:#CC6;
padding:10px;
overflow:hidden;
 } 
 /*]]>*/
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on there, I've simplified the HTML and CSS:

CSS:

```
.leftCol {
float: left;
width: 50%;
background-color: #ccc;
height: 60px;
}
.rightColContainer {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
.rightCol1 {
background-color: #333;
height: 30px;
}
.rightCol2 {
background-color: #777;
height: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="leftCol">columncontent1</div>
    <div class="rightColContainer">
        <div class="rightCol1">columncontent2</div>
        <div class="rightCol2">columncontent3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You only need to 'contain' the right hand column to stop the 'stacked column' flowing incorrectly.

Comment: ok. using the css above, why is the code in the javascript taken from d3 site--for a rotating globe-- appearing in the left column when it should be in the right column(columncontent2).. http://jsfiddle.net/9877/TDrK5/

Comment: Line 49 `var canvas = d3.select("div").append("canvas")` selects the first <div> tag that it sees on the page, in this case it's the left column. Changing to `var canvas = d3.select(".rightCol2").append("canvas")` will select the div element with a class of .rightCol2 and append it to that.

Comment: Made an error, everywhere I wrote .rightCol2 above should be .rightCol1 - As a side note, you should also put the JavaScript at the end of the page (to give the page a chance to load first) or wrap it in a function that executes on body onload.

Comment: Thanks trvo,  you know i tried that but I did not think the '.' was necessary in the d3.select statement.   thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 actually allows you to make several columns automatically without having to have all those classes. Check out this generator: http://www.generatecss.com/css3/multi-column/

This is however only if you are trying to make your content have multiple columns like a newspaper.